# Draw VectorDrawable on canvas without antialiasing Android

Tags: android, canvas, kotlin, antialiasing, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to draw `VectorDrawable` resource on Canvas. The way I'm doing it now, is a bit complicated, so step-by-step proccess looks like:

Load `VectorDrawable` from assets, set desired size, convert it to bitmap:

```
fun getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(context: Context, drawableId: Int, width: 
   Int, height: Int): Bitmap {
   var drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId)
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
       drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable!!).mutate()
   val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
   val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
   drawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height)
   drawable.isFilterBitmap = true
   drawable.draw(canvas)
   return bitmap
}
```

Manually inflate this View:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/img1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        ...
        ///ACTUALLY, THIS VIEW IS MORE COMPLICATED WITH TextView AND SOME OTHER VIEWS   
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Layout it with desired size:

```
    val widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
    val heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
    view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec)
    view.layout(0, 0, view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight)
```

Then, I`m setting bitmap to this image View:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(view.context, drawableId, width, height))
```

Then I`m rendering this View into Bitmap, using this method:

```
    fun loadBitmapFromView(v: View, width: Int, height: Int): Bitmap {
        v.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
        v.buildDrawingCache();
        if (v.drawingCache != null)
            return v.drawingCache

        val b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val c = Canvas(b)
        v.draw(c)
        return b
    }
```

And finally, draw it on canvas:

```
    bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(view, width, height)
    matrix.reset()
    matrix.postTranslate(translation.left, translation.top)
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null)
```

My test image is a simple circle. If I'm trying to draw it small (25px:25px), there are a **lot of pixel artifacts on edges**.
Width and height variables from code above is taken from drawingRect, that I'm trying to draw on canvas, so, at the first step, I`m trying to load resource with target size, that no additional scaling required.
Also, I understand, that there are a better way to draw bitmap on canvas, without using view hierarchy, but I need it to get some aligning benefits from it (align text at center of image, or using constraint layout, autosize text etc...)

**EDIT 1**
Here is an example:
[image: The bigger circle drawn normally, smaller one had artifacts]

[image: And if i zoom screenshot]

Comment: Bitmap resizing is notorious for leaving artifacts. Smoothing algorithms are relatively expensive, and not something you'd generally want to use for this sort of thing. I'm sure there's a package out there that can do this for you, but I wouldn't count on built-in solution. Scalable vectors are your friend, but I know that things aren't always that simple.

Comment: If you have to use bitmaps, it's often helpful to minimize scaling by creating multiple scaled versions ahead of time with image processing software and then loading the nearest-size version dynamically. You can still scale a little bit if needed to get the perfect fit, but this will help to minimize the artifacts.

Comment: @JDB I'm already use Vector Resource, at the first step im loading VectorDrawable from resources, set desired size to this vector, and then. convert it to bitmap.

Comment: @pskink I'm trying to draw a view with image and text, on a canvas. But I really need this kind of "arcitecture"

Comment: @pskink I have a `Rect` that user drags over canvas. Size of a `Rect` is in pixels. I'm  trying to draw view inside this rect. Width and height are getting from this `Rect`. So, size that I'm passing to  `getBitmapFromVectorDrawable` corresponds to draw size as 1:1

Comment: @pskink I've attached images